# generate pre signed url s3 with KMS servcer side encryption

Tags: python, amazon-s3, aws-cli, amazon-kms

Is there a way to generate a presigned url S3 for a private file encrypted with **KMS** Key using **Python** or **AWS cli**?

I searched in boto3 library docs and  AWS cli docs, but i didn't find anything about KMS.

Thank you in advance